# How to fix: "The query pattern 'zeige mir deine $media:media-Seite' contains an undefined parameter (name: 'media-Seite' type: 'media')"

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When I'm testing my dialogflow agent for google assistant, It is throwing me an error.

> The query pattern 'zeige mir deine $media:media-Seite' contains an undefined parameter (name: 'media-Seite' type: 'media')

The simulator was expected to open but instead, it is throwing this error again and again

Any ideas on how to solve this error?

my code of agent.json

```
{
  "description": "Use this agent in your app so it can answer support related inquiries and provided a channel for users to contact your developers or support representatives.",
  "language": "en",
  "shortDescription": "Support and CRM related conversations",
  "examples": "User: Who created you?\nUser: Tell your developers I love you.\nUser: Report bug: It\u0027s not working!\nUser: What\u0027s your Facebook page?\nUser: I want to join the beta testing group.\nUser: Search for your developers phone number.\nUser: What\u0027s your developers email?\nUser: Do you have Instagram account?",
  "activeAssistantAgents": [
    "smalltalk-domain-on",
    "smalltalk-fulfillment-on"
  ],
  "disableInteractionLogs": false,
  "disableStackdriverLogs": true,
  "googleAssistant": {
    "googleAssistantCompatible": true,
    "welcomeIntentSignInRequired": false,
    "startIntents": [],
    "systemIntents": [],
    "endIntentIds": [],
    "oAuthLinking": {
      "required": false,
      "grantType": "AUTH_CODE_GRANT"
    },
    "voiceType": "MALE_1",
    "capabilities": [],
    "protocolVersion": "V2",
    "autoPreviewEnabled": true,
    "isDeviceAgent": false
  },
  "defaultTimezone": "America/New_York",
  "webhook": {
    "url": "https://us-central1-barcode-app-for-university.cloudfunctions.net/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "available": true,
    "useForDomains": false,
    "cloudFunctionsEnabled": true,
    "cloudFunctionsInitialized": true
  },
  "isPrivate": true,
  "customClassifierMode": "use.instead",
  "mlMinConfidence": 0.3,
  "supportedLanguages": [
    "de",
    "es",
    "fr",
    "it",
    "ja",
    "pt",
    "pt-br",
    "ru",
    "zh-hk",
    "zh-tw"
  ],
  "onePlatformApiVersion": "v2beta1",
  "analyzeQueryTextSentiment": false,
  "enabledKnowledgeBaseNames": [],
  "knowledgeServiceConfidenceAdjustment": -0.4,
  "dialogBuilderMode": false
}
```

Comment: Can you post an agent export?

Comment: shared the code

Comment: I meant a DialogFlow export zip. Put it in a s3 bucket and make the file public. BTW have you tried without the dash character?